# Chrome jumps back to top of page after animating the scrollTop to a lower position in window onLoad

Tags: google-chrome, onload, scrolltop, jquery-migrate

After upgrading our site from jQuery 1.10.2 to jQuery 3.3.1, we have the following problem.

We have this JavaScript that makes the page jump to position 500 after loading.

```
$(window).on("load", function () {
    $("body, html").animate({ scrollTop: 500 }, 1);
});
```

This works fine in Firefox.

In Chrome, however, after scrolling to this position, it scrolls back up to the top of the page. When I step through in Chrome JavaScript debugging, after scrolling down, this scrolling back up occurs at this code in the jquery-3.3.1 file:

```
// Animations created synchronously will run synchronously
function createFxNow() {
    window.setTimeout( function() {
        fxNow = undefined;
    } );
    return ( fxNow = Date.now() );
}
```

How can I (1) prevent Chrome from scrolling back up, or (2) attach my code on a later page cycle hook, something like `$(window).on("completelyLoaded")` etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved this by using two nested `$(document).ready` statements:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("body, html").animate({ scrollTop: 500 }, 1);
    });
});
```

This works apparently because the ready callbacks are invoked in the order they where assigned. When the outer ready callback is invoked, all other scripts should have their ready callbacks already assigned. So assigning your ready callback (the inner one) now will lead to yours being the last one. In other words, it works because jQuery executes event handlers in the order they were added and adding an event handler in your event handler is as late as you can get.

Comment: It is not a "solution". Your solution merely ran scroll on DOM ready event and then a millisecond later (after browser tried to scroll up) you run another code that will scroll it back.

I just ran into very same problem. I can reproduce it even with Javascript off in Chrome. What I observed: when page was loaded with anchor #bottom it jumped on bottom. If I have document.documentElement.scrollTop=10000 in inline javascript just before closing <body> it scrolls down and immediatelly back up. There is no javascript then this single line.